# Oracle - Export DDL and Data from Schema in correct order

Tags: oracle, export, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I need to create a copy of DDL and Data from an Oracle 12cR1 schema.
I can't use the SYS or other High Privileges user.
I can only use SQL DEVELOPER using the schema credentials.
The rights I have are:

- Create and alter object privileges within the schema (such as CREATE
  TABLE).
- Insert, read, update and delete data privileges on the tables
  within the schema.
- Execute privileges on the stored procedures,
  functions and packages within the schema.

I can use Oracle SQL Developer or other third party tool.
I have used the "Database Export" functions, but I ahve found no way to get both the DDL and the INSERT queries in the correct order. Some table have dependencies, so I need to respect a logic order for both DDL and Queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use a tool which is designed to do such a task, and that's [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-17FAE261-0972-4220-A2E4-44D479F519D4) (Export & Import). It requires you to acquire privileges on a directory which resides on the database server, and that's something that a privileged (SYS) user creates and grants. If there's a DBA there, ask them to provide it for you.

If there's none, you can still use the [Original EXP utility](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-901CBBE0-65FB-439E-942D-F2038C18BCD2.htm#SUTIL3634) which creates a DMP file on your own computer.

The advantage of the *export* is that Oracle handles everything that seems to bother you.

If I were you, I wouldn't do it *manually*, there's really no need to do it that way. Apart from the fact that it is time-consuming, you'll have to take care about foreign key constraints, create *slow* INSERT INTO statements ... shortly, don't do it. Use (Data Pump) export and import.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all the constraints and triggers first, then insert the data. After data loaded, enable them all.

You can also try to use PL/SQL Developer to export the objects first. This tool exports objects in dependency order. Then export the data, but not sure it exports the data in dependency, you can try if there are disable constraints/triggers option when export.